# How to put my block in catalog_product_view page

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, blocks, catalog, xml

[image]My **XML** code is here

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="demo/demo" before="product.description" name="demo" template="demo/demo.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

i want to put my block under **product.info** and above **product.description**

i dont to change any core file and dont want to use **getChildHtml** method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="alert.urls"> 
            <block type="total/prototal"  name="total_prototal" template="total.phtml" />  
        </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

make sure this line must be exist in **view.phtml** file:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the view file of your theme and add this at where you are willing to display the content..

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('modulename/blockname')->getFunctionName()->setTemplate('path_to_template');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the order of your inserted blocks by the node's attribute `before` and `after`. See http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/controlling-block-order to get more info.
**But**, as you are setting your `demo.demo` block as a child of `product.info` it will **not** be rendered as child block, as long as you are not rendering it by `getChildHtml` inside `catalog/product/view.phtml` (product.info's template file). 
Set your block not inside `product.info` but outside, right before it by the descripted technique mentioned above:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <block type="demo/demo" before="product.info" name="demo" template="demo/demo.phtml" />
</catalog_product_view>
```

Child blocks are not automatically rendered by iterating through its children. There are just a few block types where this is true. See http://blog.philwinkle.com/the-most-misunderstood-concept-in-magento/ to get an understanding about this and the misconception of blocks in Magento.

> Auto-rendered blocks
>
> When defined in a layout, any block of type core/text_list will automatically render all its children. While core/text will automatically render itself it really only should contain text and therefore is not useful for layout purpose

and

> Other blocks
>
> Any other block type will need to be rendered manually. Provide the
>   block an alias which can then be passed to getChildHtml, returning the
>   content which you then echo.

to give you a tl;dr.

Comment: My xml is 

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
    </default>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="demo/demo" name="demo" template="demo/demo.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>




i am trying to develop my extension and i want put this block under **product.info**

is there any other way to put this block in product.info with out changing core files

Comment: Use `after="product.info"` as attribute of your XML node if you want your output be rendered after product.info. Please understand that you can't change the order of the product.info children without editing template files or using dirty tricks.